# Find slope of the tangent of a curve passing through fixed point

Tags: calculus

I need to find the slope of the tangent of $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-10}$ that pass through point $(0,0)$.

The derivative of $f(x)$ is $1/(\sqrt{2x-10})$.

Comment: Now set up the slope intercept form with f'(a) as slope and 0 as y-intercept.

Comment: Pay attention to the domain!

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento  it never says that $(0,0)$ should lie on the curve. It is an external point which lies on the tangent.

Comment: @MattG88 domain is fine. $(0,0)$ is an external point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the given curve is a branch of a parabola. Since the tangent line passes through $(0,0)$. Therefore it is of the form $y=mx$. Now find the intersection of this with the given curve by solving
\begin{align*}
mx & = \sqrt{2x-10}\\
m^2x^2 & = 2x-10\\
m^2x^2-2x+10 & = 0.
\end{align*}
For this to be a tangent the line should intersect the curve at coincident points, meaning the roots of the above quadratic must be equal. Thus
$$4-40m^2 =0 \implies m=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}.$$
Keeping in mind that this is the upper branch of the parabola. $m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$.

[image]

Comment: :D  Good catch!  :P

Comment: @AnuragA What did you do between m^2x^2-2x+10 = 0 and 4-40m^2 = 0 ?

Comment: That should be @Anurag A who evaluated m by zero determinant..

Comment: @Ismael When you solve a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, to have equal roots, the discriminant $b^2-4ac=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a point $P(x_P,y_P)$ where the line $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$ will be tangent to $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-10}$, so if $(x_0,y_0)\equiv O$, we have:

$$y=mx$$
$$m_P={1\over\sqrt{2x_P-10}}$$

thus $y={1\over\sqrt{2x_P-10}}x$ is a line through the origin tangent to $f(x)$ at $P$. Now we know that this line must be tangent to $f(x)$ at $P$ so it must pass through this point, hence:

$$y_P={1\over\sqrt{2x_P-10}}x_P$$

but $y_P=\sqrt{2x_P-10}$, so:
$$\sqrt{2x_P-10}={1\over\sqrt{2x_P-10}}x_P\longrightarrow 2x_P-10=x_P\Longrightarrow x_P=10$$

So we get $P(10,\sqrt{10})$ and $m_P={1\over\sqrt{2x_P-10}}={1\over\sqrt{10}}$.

Comment: $y={1\over\sqrt{2x-10}}x$ is NOT a line. You should have a different variable for $x$ in the expression for $m$. Moreover the slope should be $1/\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: @AnuragA yes sure, I corrected it, thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

$$ y = f(x) \tag1$$
$$  y^2 = 2x -10 \tag2$$
Differentiate

$$ y y^{\prime} = 1 \tag3$$

Take standard form with shift of 5 along $x$ direction.

$$ x= ft^2 + 5 ;\, y = 2 ft \tag4$$

$ y^{\prime}$ = slope

$$ =\frac {dy}{dx}  =  \frac {dy/dt}{dx/dt} =\frac {2f}{2ft} = \frac1t \tag5 $$

Equation of tangent

$$   \frac {y-2ft}{ft^2 + 5 } = \frac1t \tag6 $$

Since it passes through origin, constant term should vanish. Cross-multiplying for constant terms,

$$ -2 ft^2 = -(5 + ft^2)\rightarrow t = \pm \sqrt 10 \tag7 $$

$$ Slope =1/t = \pm \frac{1}{ \sqrt 10} \tag8$$

Positive sign for tangent in first quadrant, negative in fourth.

Answer (score -1):

The tangent is given by $$mx+ b,$$ with $m$ being the derivative of $f$ in $x=a$ ($x$-value to be evaluated).

Comment: This hint is very generic and doesn't help solve the problem. Please try to be more specific.